# How to read in a video file as grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv

When you read in an image, there is a flag you can set to `0` to force it as grayscale.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(file, 0); // keeps it grayscale
```

Is there an equivalent for videos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There's not.**

You need to query the frames and convert them to grayscale yourself.

Using the C interface: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444370/176769

With the C++ interface:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    // print error msg
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("gray",1);

Mat frame;
Mat gray;
for(;;)
{
    cap >> frame;

    cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    imshow("gray", gray);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) 
        break;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Sure declaring `gray` outside of the `for` scope, together with `frame`, will prevent the expensive memory allocation and deallocation of this large image every frame. Fixing that would be worth an up-vote.