# QTKit didn't find any attached Video Input Devices

Tags: c++, c, opencv, camera, quicktime

The following error occurs whenever I try to run a [simple application to grab frames from the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408961/176769) of a Macbook Pro 13" (built-in iSight):

```
QTKit didn't find any attached Video Input Devices!
Warning, camera failed to properly initialize!
Cleaned up camera.
```

I've tried passing -1, 0 and as parameters to `cvCreateCameraCapture()` and the `cv::VideoCapture` object but none worked. It's important to say that I used OpenCV 2.3.1 on this machine for quite a while and it worked fine passing -1 as parameter.

This problem seems to happen with OpenCV v2.4.2 and v2.4.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

After a little bit of research I found that [QTKit is the QuickTime Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and has nothing to do with [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). So the next logical thing to do was to disable *QTKit* from the OpenCV build, and the way to do that is through the flag `-DWITH_QUICKTIME=YES`, which forces OpenCV to be build with QuickTime for Video I/O instead of *QTKit*.

Unfortunately this solution didn't work either, since it caused several compiling errors that I don't want to deal with:

```
[ 32%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_qt.cpp.o
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:75: error: ‘Movie’ does not name a type
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘CvCapture_QT_Movie* icvCaptureFromFile_QT(const char*)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:100: warning: declaration of ‘did_enter_movies’ shadows a global declaration [-Wshadow]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:67: warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:103: error: ‘EnterMovies’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘int icvOpenFile_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, const char*)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:142: error: ‘ClearMoviesStickyError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:145: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:161: error: ‘kQTPOSIXPathStyle’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:161: error: ‘QTNewDataReferenceFromFullPathCFString’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:169: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:169: error: ‘newMovieActive’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:169: error: ‘newMovieAsyncOK’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:170: error: ‘NewMovieFromDataRef’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:190: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:190: error: ‘nextTimeMediaSample’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:190: error: ‘nextTimeEdgeOK’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:191: error: ‘GetMovieNextInterestingTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:205: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:212: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:213: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:213: error: ‘GetMovieBox’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:218: error: ‘QTNewGWorld’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:220: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:220: error: ‘SetMovieGWorld’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘int icvClose_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:243: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:247: error: ‘DisposeGWorld’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:248: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:248: error: ‘DisposeMovie’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘double icvGetProperty_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:264: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:281: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:281: error: ‘GetMovieTimeScale’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:286: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:286: error: ‘GetMovieDuration’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:300: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:300: error: ‘GetMovieDuration’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:301: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:301: error: ‘GetMovieTimeScale’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘int icvSetProperty_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int, double)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:331: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:351: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:351: error: ‘GetMovieTimeScale’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:356: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:356: error: ‘GetMovieDuration’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:370: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:370: error: ‘nextTimeStep’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:371: error: ‘GetMovieNextInterestingTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:372: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:385: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:385: error: ‘nextTimeStep’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:386: error: ‘GetMovieNextInterestingTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:387: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:408: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:408: error: ‘nextTimeStep’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:409: error: ‘GetMovieNextInterestingTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:410: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘int icvGrabFrame_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:441: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:449: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:449: error: ‘SetMovieTimeValue’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:450: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:458: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:458: error: ‘GetMovieTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:462: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:462: error: ‘nextTimeStep’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:462: error: ‘GetMovieNextInterestingTime’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘const void* icvRetrieveFrame_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:484: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:494: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:494: error: ‘UpdateMovie’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:495: error: ‘GetMoviesError’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:503: error: ‘struct CvCapture_QT_Movie’ has no member named ‘myMovie’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:503: error: ‘MoviesTask’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:515: error: ‘GetGWorldPixMap’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:516: error: ‘LockPixels’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:517: error: ‘GetPixBaseAddr’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:517: error: ‘GetPixRowBytes’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:523: error: ‘UnlockPixels’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: At global scope:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:556: error: ‘SeqGrabComponent’ does not name a type
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:557: error: ‘SGChannel’ does not name a type
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:560: error: ‘ImageSequence’ does not name a type
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: In function ‘CvCapture_QT_Cam* icvCaptureFromCam_QT(int)’:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:590: error: ‘EnterMovies’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp: At global scope:
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:609: warning: unused parameter ‘capture’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:609: warning: unused parameter ‘property_id’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:616: warning: unused parameter ‘capture’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:616: warning: unused parameter ‘property_id’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:616: warning: unused parameter ‘value’ [-Wunused-parameter]
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: ‘SGChannel’ was not declared in this scope
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘raw_data’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘short’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:854: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:238: warning: ‘int icvClose_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:261: warning: ‘double icvGetProperty_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:328: warning: ‘int icvSetProperty_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int, double)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:438: warning: ‘int icvGrabFrame_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:481: warning: ‘const void* icvRetrieveFrame_QT_Movie(CvCapture_QT_Movie*, int)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:98: warning: ‘CvCapture_QT_Movie* icvCaptureFromFile_QT(const char*)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:572: warning: ‘int icvOpenCamera_QT(CvCapture_QT_Cam*, int)’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:573: warning: ‘int icvClose_QT_Cam(CvCapture_QT_Cam*)’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:609: warning: ‘double icvGetProperty_QT_Cam(CvCapture_QT_Cam*, int)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:616: warning: ‘int icvSetProperty_QT_Cam(CvCapture_QT_Cam*, int, double)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:576: warning: ‘int icvGrabFrame_QT_Cam(CvCapture_QT_Cam*)’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:577: warning: ‘const void* icvRetrieveFrame_QT_Cam(CvCapture_QT_Cam*, int)’ declared ‘static’ but never defined
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:586: warning: ‘CvCapture_QT_Cam* icvCaptureFromCam_QT(int)’ defined but not used
/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_qt.cpp:853: warning: ‘icvDataProc_QT_Cam’ defined but not used
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_qt.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Try to build OpenCV without QT and check.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. I also forced OpenCV to use QUICKTIME instead of libdc1394, and then there were compiling errors related to `*DisposeGWorld* was not declared in this scope` (which indicates OpenCV is using a deprecated Mac API).

Comment: What do you mean didn't work for me? Was it error? If yes, then can you post it?

Comment: [I reported this as an Issue](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2726).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I reported this problem](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2726) but now I think it might be specific to my system, I'll try to perform more tests to clear it up.

Anyway, here's what I had to to fix the issue:

Edit **modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm** and jump to line 313 to see the implementation of:

```
int CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int cameraNum) {
```

Our changes will be made to this method, so locate the following block:

```
if (cameraNum >= 0) { 
    int nCameras = [devices count];
    if( cameraNum < 0 || cameraNum >= nCameras )   
        return 0;
    device = [devices objectAtIndex:cameraNum] ;
} else {
    device = [QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo]  ;
}
```

and **replace** it by:

```
if (cameraNum >= 0) { 
    int nCameras = [devices count];
    if( cameraNum > nCameras )
        return 0;
    cameraNum--;
    device = [devices objectAtIndex:cameraNum] ;
} else {
    device = [QTCaptureDevice defaultInputDeviceWithMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo]  ;
}
```

Recompile OpenCV and don't forget to install it on your system again.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the camera solved the problem. 
`sudo killall VDCAssistant`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did not find any solution. By trial and error, I found that my `OpenCV` version is corrupted. As a result, I deleted it and install a new fresh one. You can use one of these two options:
**1. Terminal**
run `brew uninstall opencv3` to uninstall `opencv`
then install it using `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` command.

**2. Anaconda**
Actually, I used this method for my own problem.

1. open anaconda
2. go to the environment section and select your environment as follow:
   [image]
   then click on installed and search for `opencv`:
   [image]
   select `opencv` package and uninstall it. then try to re-install `opencv` by selecting not installed and searching for `opencv`. be careful to install the correct version.
   [image]