# OpenCV: not authorized to capture video - mac python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.5.1, and I try to execute this code in python with IDLE, to capture my camera video:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

And that returns an error:

```
OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...

Process ended with exit code -9.
```

I go in  System preferences -> Security and privacy -> privacy -> camera
I want to enable the camera access for IDLE but the IDLE app doesn't appears in the list of applications, and I can't add any apps.

I don't know how to enable the camera permission for IDLE or how to resolve the problem.

Comment: if you run it in the terminal, it should prompt you to agree to use video. Once you click OK, terminal is added to the list of apps. With IDLE, I assume it is the same or a similar experience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV command line app can't access camera under macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084303/opencv-command-line-app-cant-access-camera-under-macos-mojave)